# Add method to all controllers AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a simple app and couple of controllers. In each `controller` I defined a `"init"` function. I do this because I want that it can be easy to "refresh" the controller - just call the `init` function like this: `$scope.init()`.

In other words, something like `Page_Load`  event in `.Net` (A function that if you defined it in your code it will be firing when the page is load.

I'm trying to use `decorator` function that run for each controller, but I don't know how to finish this to accomplish the mission.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.decorator('$controller', ['$delegate', function ($delegate) {
    return function (constructor, locals) {
        var controller = $delegate.apply(null, arguments);
        // Never got hear
        if (locals.$scope && locals.$scope.init) {
            console.log('init');
            locals.$scope.init();
        }

        return angular.extend(function () {
            return controller();
        }, controller);
    };
}]);

myApp.controller('ctrl1', function($scope) {
  $scope.init = function() {
   $scope.name = 'Superhero';
  };
  
  // I don't want to call this
  $scope.init();
});

myApp.controller('ctrl2', function($scope) {
  $scope.init = function() {
   $scope.name = 'Mario';
  };
  
  // I don't want to call this
  $scope.init();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl1">
    Hello, {{name}}!
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="ctrl2">
    My name is, {{name}}!
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You add this function to scope, inside controller. So it would be added in this line

```
return angular.extend(function () {
    return controller(); //here
}, controller);
```

you can simple save this value, can call it, like

```
return angular.extend(function () {
    var c = controller(); //here save controller object

    if (locals.$scope && locals.$scope.init) {
        console.log('init'); 
        locals.$scope.init();
    }

    return c;//return controller;
}, controller);
```

Sample:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.decorator('$controller', ['$delegate', function ($delegate) {
    return function (constructor, locals) {
        var controller = $delegate.apply(null, arguments);

        return angular.extend(function () {

          var c = controller();
          
        // Never got hear
        if (locals.$scope && locals.$scope.init) {
            console.log('init');
            locals.$scope.init();
        }
          
          return c;
        }, controller);
    };
}]);

myApp.controller('ctrl1', function($scope) {
 $scope.init = function() {
   $scope.name = 'Superhero';
  };
  
});

myApp.controller('ctrl2', function($scope) {
 $scope.init = function() {
   $scope.name = 'Mario';
  };
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl1">
    Hello, {{name}}!
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="ctrl2">
    My name is, {{name}}!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works like charm, Thanks!